# What is the effect of multiplying a matrix by diagonal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, $T\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, $T$ is diagonal matrix with positive diagonal elements.

I am interested in characteristics of new matrix $\hat{B}=BT$, i.e. what will be the difference between $B$ and $\hat{B}$, and what characteristics will be same.

For example: $\mathrm{rank}(\hat{B})=\mathrm{rank}(B)$, $\det(\hat{B}'\hat{B})=\det(B'B)\det{T}^2$.

I want to understand what is the effect of multiplying a diagonal matrix $T$ on $B$.

Comment: Multiplying an arbitrary matrix $B$ by a square matrix $M$ on the right has the effect of doing column operations on $B$. Try this with $M=T$ and see.

Comment: You could experiment with 3x3 matrices.